# format of var[] keyword.c/freeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I want to add some items to `var[]` in `keyword.c` file (in freeBSD), but I don't know format of each member! can anybody help me?

example in:
`"{"tt", "TT ", NULL, 0, tname, 0, CHAR, NULL, 0}"` what's the meaning of each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking at the code for ps(1). The fields are described in the `var` struct definition in `/usr/src/bin/ps/ps.h`.